# How to do the communication between Kendo-UI for Jquery and Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui

I want to use scheduler in Angular2 base project, 
since Kendo-UI for Angular2 dose not include scheduler function. 
Is there any way to use jquery scheduler in angular2?

I already included jquery scheduler in angular2 and every thing goes well.
except I can't routing a new page by angular2 routerLink from scheduler tooltip.
How can I solve this routing problem?

e.g.)

index.html:

```
<script id="hoverTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <a class="waves-effect waves-blue" routerLink="/customer-view">Customer</a></script>
```

customer.routes.ts:

```
export const CustomerRoutes: Route[] = [{
path: 'customer-view',
component: CustomerViewComponent }];
```

Comment: Would be great if you provide a plunker that illustrates your problem. I know that content of your `hoverTemplate` is not compiled by angular

Comment: @ yurzui, Thank you for your answer, I am sorry it's hard to create a plunker, the hoverTemplate is a template for the tooptip in the scheduler event.
I did following to use this template in Angular2  component ts file.

this.tooltip = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement.children[0]);
 this.tooltip.kendoTooltip({
            content: kendo.template($('#hoverTemplate').html()),//hoverTemplate,
            filter: ".k-event",

Comment: The easiest way to do it working is subscribing on `click` event and use `router.navigate` or `router.navigateByUrl` to navigate to `custom-view`.

Comment: See example http://jsfiddle.net/56KWZ/2/

Comment: @ yurzui, It works, Thank you again.